# Why can't I use map to collect the properties of an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of th's that I want to get the textContent property from and put in a list. map() does not work as expected:

```
table_headers = $("#careerStats table thead tr th");
headers.map(function(obj) {return(obj.textContent);});
[]
```

When I write an iterative version of this, I am able to get an array of values as I expected:

```
values = [];
for (i=0; i<table_headers.length; i++) {    
    values.push(table_headers[i].textContent); 
}

values
["Year", "Team", "LG", "W", "L", "ERA", "G", "GS", "CG", "SHO", "SV", "SVO", "IP", "H", "R", "ER", "HR", "HB", "BB", "IBB", "SO", "AVG", "WHIP", "GO/AO", "Year", "Team", "LG", "W", "L", "ERA", "G", "GS", "CG", "SHO", "SV", "SVO", "IP", "H", "R", "ER", "HR", "HB", "BB", "IBB", "SO", "AVG", "WHIP", "GO/AO"]
```

I must be misunderstanding something about Javascript prototypes and/or map().

Comment: possible to provide a fiddle?

Comment: Are you assigning the result of map to another variable? Map does not mutate the original array.

Comment: Well, `headers` is not `table_headers`, and `map` has to return somewhere as it creates a new array, and finally, you're using jQuery's `.map()`, not the native `Array.map`, so you'll probably need a `get()`

Comment: Map will return a new array which will have your result. You are not assigning map result to table_headers and hence it will have the values.
Sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/snh2dhh4/

Comment: Sorry, my code example was slightly misleading. The output from $(...).map is an empty array. I was not assigning it to a variable, but that's what it looked like. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using JavaScript's [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - it's jQuery's [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) which behaves in a different fashion:
    jQuery's map has a following signature:

```
$(selector).map(function (index, value) { ... })
```

You have to use the second arguments to access selected element:

```
table_headers.map(function(idx, obj) {return(obj.textContent);});
```

---

There is another difference between jQuery's map and JS's map. jQuery returns a new **wrapper**, not a plain array. To get the underlying array, you can access it using [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
mapped_table_headers.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
table_headers = $("#careerStats table thead tr th");
var A = table_headers.map(function() {return this.textContent;}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the jQuery selector is returning a JavaScript array. It is actually returning a jQuery Object. The jQuery Object has a lot of similar functionality to a JavaScript array (and also a lot of extra functionality). However, when you call `.map()` on a jQuery object, you are calling jQuery's `.map()` which behaves differently than `.map()` on a JavaScript array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.